# How to assign text class based on line height (quantize height to discrete H1, H2, H3, p)?

Tags: python, pdf, markdown, classification, histogram

**TLDR:** I am converting a PDF to MarkDown and I need a heuristic that will allow me to assign styles (H1, H2, H3, regular, caption) to lines, based on their heights. Essentially, I have a `list[tuple(str, float)]` of lines and their heights that I need to covert into a `list[tuple(str, int)]` where the integer `[1-5]` is the style of the line.

I am using [`PyMuPDF`](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/) to parse PDF documents and I convert them to a format consumable by an LLM. I decided to convert them to MarkDown because it is plain-text (directly understandable by an LLM), while still having the most crucial structural information about the document (like heading, chapters, etc.).

Firstly, I open the document,

```py
import fitz
doc = fitz.open("to_process.pdf")
```

I extract `dict`s for each of its pages,

```py
page_datas = []
for page in doc:
    text_page = page.get_textpage(flags=fitz.TEXT_MEDIABOX_CLIP)
    page_data = text_page.extractDICT(sort=True)
    page_datas.append(page_data)
```

And I remove non-horizontal lines (as a means of cleaning the document up).

```py
for page_data in page_datas:
    for block in page_data["blocks"]:
        block["lines"] = [line for line in block["lines"] if line["dir"] == (1.0, 0.0)]
```

At this point, I can start actually converting the document into MarkDown.

Compared to a PDF, which can have arbitrary styling applied to text, MarkDown distinguishes only a few text classes, such as headings H1-H3. As such, I need to "quantize" the continuously-sized lines into these discrete classes. I decided to create a list of all line heights in the document and based on that, assign them categories. For example, if there are only two lines in the document that have a large size, they are most likely the title. If there are a few lines with a large (but not the largest size) they are probably headings. If most lines' heights fit into a specific range (say `[11.8-12.1]`) then these are probably lines from the main body of the document. Any smaller lines are probably captions, comments or some other additional information.

I can get a list of all line_heights in the document like this:

```py
fitz.TOOLS.set_small_glyph_heights(True)
line_heights = []
for page_data in page_datas:
    for block in page_data["blocks"]:
        for line in block["lines"]:
            line_heights.append(line["bbox"][3] - line["bbox"][1])
```

I can round the heights to the nearest `0.1` and create a "histogram" of them like this:

```py
line_heights = [round(height, 1) for height in line_heights]
line_heights = sorted(list(Counter(line_heights).items()), reverse=True)
```

Still, this leaves my with a histogram with (in general) an arbitrary number of line heights. I can manually assign heights to categories based on looking at a PDF, but different PDFs can have different font size ranges in general. For one PDF, I get:

| Height | Count | Manual Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14.4 | 1 | H1 |
| 14.3 | 1 | H1 |
| 12.8 | 5 | H2 |
| 12.1 | 1 | H2 |
| 12.0 | 2 | H2 |
| 11.7 | 1 | H2 |
| 10.1 | 15 | p |
| 10.0 | 24 | p |
| 9.9 | 9 | p |
| 9.1 | 5 | sup |
| 9.0 | 18 | sup |
| 8.9 | 6 | sup |

In the case of this file, there are no H3-H6.

How could I do this programatically?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a rule-based approach to handle the general issue of attempting to find structure in an unstructured (PDF) document.

The reality is that most PDF documents you see will be produced by a handful of libraries or tools.

For instance, in a corporate setting, you might see a lot of PDF documents that originate from "Word > convert/save as PDF". And then the font sizes will simply be the default font sizes Word assigns to each header.

So you might have a rule that says "If the producer meta data is Microsoft Word, AND the font size is XX, this is heading level YY".

And the same for open office, or LaTeX, etc.

After you've handled all the easy options, you can do the harder options (such as the general case).

For a more general case, you might use a neural network that you can feed all kinds of properties into:

- relative x-position of text
- relative y-position of text
- color difference between text and its closest neighbour
- length of text
- proportion of text that is not a stopword
- etc

Then comes the rather painstaking task of running this against let's say 100 documents and building a training/testing set.

I have a large corpus of PDF documents you can use.
It's on my [GitHub](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/pdf-corpus).

Comment: Thanks, this seems like an effective and simple solution. I didn't think of this. I'll have a try.